# How to update the specific element in JSON data with setState in React

Tags: reactjs

I am working in React with TypeScript. I am using the below JSON format to build the tree structure to display the content as folder. I stored the below JSON data in state object as treeViewData.

```js
{
  "path": "Parent Site",
  "name": "Parent Site",
  "type": "directory",
  "isRoot": true,
  "children": [
    {
      "path": "Parent Site/Sub Site 1",
      "name": "Sub Site 1",
      "type": "directory",
      "children": [
        {
          "path": "Parent Site/Sub Site 1/Documents",
          "name": "Documents",
          "type": "directory",
          "children": []
        },
        {
          "path": "Parent Site/Sub Site 1/My Documents",
          "name": "Documents",
          "type": "directory",
          "children": [
            {
              "path": "Parent Site/Sub Site 1/My Documents/Folder1",
              "name": "Folder1",
              "type": "directory”,
"children": []
            },
            {
              "path": "Parent Site/Sub Site 1/My Documents/Folder2",
              "name": "Folder2",
              "type": "directory”,
"children": []
            }
          ]
        },
        {
          "path": "Parent Site/Sub Site 1/My New Documents",
          "name": "Documents",
          "type": "directory",
          "children": []
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "path": "Parent Site/Sub Site 2",
      "name": "Sub Site 2",
      "type": "directory",
      "children": [
        {
          "path": "Parent Site/Sub Site 2/Documents",
          "name": "Documents",
          "type": "directory",
          "children": [
            {
              "path": "Parent Site/Sub Site 2/Documents/Folder1",
              "name": "Folder1",
              "type": "directory”,
"children": []
            },
            {
              "path": "Parent Site/Sub Site 2/Documents/Folder2",
              "name": "Folder2",
              "type": "directory”,
"children": []
            },
            {
              "path": "Parent Site/Sub Site 2/Documents/Folder3",
              "name": "Folder3",
              "type": "directory",
              "children": []
            }
          ]
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

From the above JSON data, I want to insert new set of properties in the Children object. Let us consider the below child which is resided in the Parent Site/Sub Site 2.

```
"path": "Parent Site/Sub Site 2/Documents/Folder1",
```

In this current node, Children array is empty. I want to insert new set of four properties to be added like below.

```js
"path": "Parent Site/Sub Site 2/Documents/Folder1/Inside New Folder",
 "name": "Inside New Folder",
"type": "directory”,
"children":[]
```

How to do this in React? How to perform the setState operation of this scenario? Please help me.

Thanks
Philip

Comment: You'll have to write a recursive function that goes through all of the nested objects/arrays and when it finds the path you want to find then you should update the children array of that particular object.

Comment: can you please share the example for this?

Comment: I wrote a recursive function and update the state with prevState concept. It is working fine now.

Comment: Nice, you can answer your own question.